# How to map rras dhcp from remote console

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, putty, rras

So I had been following [This tutorial](http://techgenix.com/configure-vpn-windows-server-2012-r2/) on how to set up VPN on my server. It's some dedicated server I have with Strato, and can acces through RDP.

The tutorial follows some very simple steps

- Execute `Install-WindowsFeature DirectAccess-VPN -IncludeManagementTools` in power shell.
- Open RRAS, and follow the setup wizard.

With big red markings, not much can go wrong there.

However, after clicking ok on a message stating `“To support the relaying of DHCP messages from remote access clients, you must configure the properties of the DHCP Relay Agent with the IP address of your DHCP server.”` my RDP connection promptly got closed, and I became unable to access it.

Now through strato I do have access to a SSH putty console, allowing me to do things in cmd/powershell/sh with full admin rights. However, all online resources speak of rras, and it's UI interface, which I can't currently access.

Now I figure that either undoing the first VPN steps or completing the DHCP linking will allow me to access the server again through RDP.
Which leads up to my question, can I round up this configuration through console, or thus undo it so that the server becomes accessible through RDP again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was an alternative to the 2 options.

by executing `net stop remoteaccess` through the remote connection, the server became reachable through RDP again.